# How to fill a triangle enclosed by three non-parallel lines

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

I cannot understand how to fill the triangle, and only it, made by the given lines and the x-axis. Here is the code I have tried:

```
Clear[f, g, plot, reg];
f[x_] = -x + 6;
g[x_] = 2 x - 4;
plot = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 23}, 
PlotStyle -> {Darker@Cyan, Darker@Green}, AspectRatio -> Automatic];    
reg = RegionPlot[{f[x] <= g[x] && y <= 8/3}, {x, 2, 6}, {y, 0, 8/3}, 
PlotStyle -> LightGray, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[reg, plot, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}],
Axes -> True, Frame -> False]
```

whose output is as follows:

[image]

Any help? Thank you.

I was messing around with the functions `f` and `g`, but I cannot find a way to fill only the triangle.

Comment: `reg = RegionPlot[{y <= g[x] && y <= f[x]}, {x, 2, 6}, {y, 0, 8/3}, 
   PlotStyle -> LightGray, BoundaryStyle -> None]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_] = -x + 6;
g[x_] = 2 x - 4;
h[x_] := Min[g[x], f[x]];
Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, 23},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> {Darker@Cyan, Darker@Green, None},
 Filling -> {3 -> {Axis, {None, Blue}}}]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Clear[f, g, reg];

f[x_] := -x + 6;
g[x_] := 2 x - 4;


reg = ImplicitRegion[y <= g[x] && y <= f[x] && y > 0, {x, y}];

p1 = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 8}
   , PlotRange -> {-1, 4}
   , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
   , PlotStyle -> {Darker@Cyan, Darker@Green}
   , PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 2}, {0, 0}}
   ];

p2 = RegionPlot[reg
   , PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[]
   , BoundaryStyle -> None];

gr = Graphics[{HatchFilling[], Rectangle[]}
   , ImageSize -> Small
   ];

legend = LineLegend[{Darker@Cyan, Darker@Green, White}
   , {f[x], g[x], TraditionalForm@reg[[1]]}
   , LegendMarkers -> {None, None, gr}
   , LegendMarkerSize -> 20];

Legended[
 Show[p1, p2]
 , Placed[legend, {0.7, 0.8}]
 ]
```

---

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that is awesome!!!